# How to authenticate AWS IOT devices through API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-api-gateway, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

I’ve got a use-case where my devices should make GET requests against my API gateway.

What would be the simplest way to have API gateway perform client authentication of the device? Is it possible to use the certificates already generated by IoT Core and used in MQTT?

Answer (score 0):

[Authorizing direct calls to AWS services using AWS IoT Core credential provider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/authorizing-direct-aws.html):

> Devices can use X.509 certificates to connect to AWS IoT Core using TLS mutual authentication protocols. Other AWS services do not support certificate-based authentication, but they can be called using AWS credentials in AWS Signature Version 4 format. The Signature Version 4 algorithm normally requires the caller to have an access key ID and a secret access key. AWS IoT Core has a credentials provider that allows you to use the built-in X.509 certificate as the unique device identity to authenticate AWS requests. This eliminates the need to store an access key ID and a secret access key on your device.